# Real and Imaginary Parts of a Complex Number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm a bit unsure how to to figure out the real and imaginary parts of some combinations of complex numbers. Here's an exercept from Palka's *Complex Function Theory*

[image]

Here, $(3.9)$ refers to the equation,

\begin{align}
w = \sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to show that given $w$ is not real and $|w| \geq 1$, that,

\begin{align}
\text{Re} \big [ (1 - w^2)^{1/2} + iw \big ] > 0, \quad \quad \text{Re} \big [ -(1 - w^2)^{1/2} + iw \big ] < 0
\end{align}

Also, how does this allow us to infer that $|\text{Re}z_1| < \pi /2$ and $|\text{Re}z_2| > \pi /2$.

Comment: I have seen this exact question here a few days ago.

Comment: @SahibaArora Corrected the question and generated a new post.